# Character in the url is changed when using window.location.search

Tags: javascript, html, url, diacritics

I have an url like: file:///C:/Users/index.html?Scale:%20Service-Qualität

When I use `window.location.search` to get the parameter in the url, in this case the parameter should be **Scale: Service-Qualität** but what I actually received was **Scale:%20Service-Qualit%C3%A4t**, I dont know why my character **ä** changed to **%C3%A4** and when I tested in the console it displayed as **Scale: Service-QualitÃ¤t**

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing two issues here.

The `ä` being converted into `%C3%A4` is called URL or [percent encoding.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

It's because URLs can't, technically, contain Unicode characters.

Browsers and servers work around this by converting non-ASCII characters in URLs to their percent encoded equivalents.

It's generally nothing to worry about.

In your case however, there seems to be an actual problem as well. The weird output in the console *could* be because your web page uses a single-byte encoding (like ISO-8859-1) instead of UTF-8.

Switching the web page to UTF-8 might solve the problem, using this Meta tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

and, of course, saving the HTML file as UTF-8 in your editor.

Comment: Hi Pekka, I tried to add the meta tag as you suggested above but it still not working

Comment: I add two meta tags: 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

Comment: Hmm, not sure what is going on then. Where exactly are you using the string? In JavaScript? Can you show how?

Comment: the procedure I am using is: in javascript I have a string URL which contains: "Scale: Service-Qualität" for example, and then I add this string to the url I want to call: window.open("index.html?"+URL, '_blank');. Then in my index.html, I get back the parameter, here what I should have is "Scale: Service-Qualität", but actually I get "Scale: Service-QualitÃ¤t"

Comment: Ah I used window.location.search to get back the parameter, and when I display it in the console: console.log (window.location.search), I see that the character is changed

Comment: Are you sure the browser's encoding is set to UTF-8 when the page is opened? Is the page where the string originates from UTF-8?

Comment: I am sorry, I am new in html so I dont really get what you mean. In my index.html, I set a meta tag like you mentioned above, what should I do also?

Comment: Go to the page, look in the browser's "encoding" or "character set" menu (it's often in the "view" menu) to see whether the tag worked. If it's not that, I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for my problem. What I need to do is decode again my url using: `decodeURIComponent(url);` then I will get again exact url string.